# SAS %_eg_WhereParam ERROR

Tags: sql, macros, sas, prompt, enterprise-guide

I have a prompt in which users can select multiple values from a dynamic list. The macro variable created by the prompt is called **promptList**.
Now I want to select only the data that has been chosen by the user in the prompt. 
So suppose the user runs the program and selects values **A, C and D** from the prompt which all go to the promptList macro variable. To filter the data, I wrote the following:

```
SELECT 
  var1,
  var2, 
  var3

    FROM 
      table1

    WHERE 
      %_eg_WhereParam(var1, promptList, IN, type = C);
```

Which in theory should only select data that have the value of var1 either **A, C or D**. However, just below the whereParam statement in the log, I am getting these errors:

```
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a SELECT.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

What am I missing here? Also, is there a better way how to access this list of values in a macro variable? Can't find any proper documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did it with query builder and the code generated by query builder looks like this:

```
%_eg_WhereParam(var1, promptList, IN, type = S, IS_EXPLICIT = 0);
```

So S (assuming String) and IS_EXPLICIT = 0 did the trick.